# Trying to apply two different caption styles using \caption, but the styles won't get applied

Tags: captions, listings

Below is my full LaTeX document.

My goal is to create two different caption styles. One style for the caption for the programming blocks (created with listings), where above the programming block, a caption with a grey background and black outline appears. This is done in `\DeclareCaptionStyle{style1}`.

Then I want a second caption style which has no style applied to it and is just used below images. This is done in `\DeclareCaptionStyle{style2}`.

Right now, the style for the programming blocks (`\DeclareCaptionStyle{style1}`) is not being applied in the document. I am not sure what is wrong with my syntax.

```
\documentclass[12pt,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, listings, caption}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\graphicspath{{./Images/}}

\tcbset{on line,
  boxsep=4pt, left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
  colframe=black,colback=lightgray,
  highlight math style={enhanced}
}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{style1}{
  font={sf,small},
  box=colorbox,boxcolor=gray,
  labelformat=empty,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{style2}{
}
\captionsetup[R]{style=style1}
\captionsetup[graphics]{style=style2}

\lstset{
  rulecolor=\color{Black},
  backgroundcolor=\color{White},
  breaklines=true,
  tabsize=4,
  showstringspaces=false
  extendedchars=\true,
  frame=single,
  framesep=3pt,
  framerule=0.4pt,
  xleftmargin=3.4pt,
  xrightmargin=3.4pt,
}

\lstdefinestyle{R}{
  language=R,
  caption={[R]{R}},
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\color{Gray}\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{Blue},
  identifierstyle=\color{Black},
  stringstyle=\color{BrickRed},
  commentstyle=\color{Green}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=R]
print("hello")
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{imagename}
\caption[graphics]{Amazing captioning text.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The optional argument of `\caption` is for the "short caption", not the `\captionsetup`. You need to create a new float type for `graphics`, or just call `\captionsetup` each time.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can you give an example of what you mean by creating a new float type for graphics?

Comment: I seem to have found an easy solution to this. Changing to `\captionsetup[lstlisting]{style=style1}` and `\captionsetup[figure]{style=style2}` appears to change the setup globally. I wasn't aware that I could directly link to the `lstlisting` and `figure` but that seems to be the easiest fix with the intended result

Comment: @JohnKormylo Will you answer?

Comment: @cfr - Nah.  He is alreacy using two different float types, so no new float type needed.  Besides, it would have used a diferent counter than figure.

Comment: @kyarudata, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `\captionsetup` to refer to `lstlisting` and `figure` did the trick.

```
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{style=style1}
\captionsetup[figure]{style=style2}
```